# finding double integral of maximum function

Tags: integration

How to find

$$
\iint_{\left[0,1\right] \times \left[0,1\right]}\max\left\{x,y\right\}
\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y?
$$

Is it possible to use
$\displaystyle{\quad\max\left\{x,y\right\} = {x + y + \left\vert\,x - y\,\right\vert \over 2}}\ ?.\quad$
I really don't have any idea about how to do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

You have two cases of course, either $x$ or $y$ is bigger.  For all $(x,y)$ lying above the line $y=x$ we are going to have that,
$$\max\{x,y\}=y$$

Also for all points $(x,y)$ lying below the line $y=x$ we will of course have,

$$\max\{x,y\}=x $$

So split your integral into the two triangular regions separated by $y=x$, and integrate the function $f(x,y)=y$ over the triangle above $y=x$, and integrate the function $g(x,y)=x$ over the triangle below the line $y=x$...and then of course add the two up.  Hope that helps!

Comment: What's kind of cool is the formula that you wrote reduces to what I was saying.  In the upper triangle region you would have $y-x>0$  So your formula reduces to just $y$, and in the lower triangle $x-y>0$ so your formula just reduces to $x$.